# How do I select between 1st day of the current month and the 1st day of the following month (from current month) in postgres

Tags: postgresql

SELECT tbl.createdate > '20211001' and tbl.createdate < '20211101'

I need the dates in the '' to change depending on the date the query is run.  For example if I schedule it to run in November it would be
SELECT tbl.createdate > '20211101' and tbls.createdate < '20211201'

and if I run it in December it would be
SELECT tbl.createdate > '20211201' and tbl.createdate < '20220101'

I need the query to run without user changing the dates.

Comment: Do you really want to not include the starting date of the current month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can use the `date_trunc()` function, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). The result is :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.createdate > date_trunc('month', Now()) 
  and tbl.createdate < (date_trunc('month', Now()) + interval '1 month')
```

Comment: To reiterate my comment above, this is going to result one day a month to not be included. Is this what you want?